# If ($ACBD$) $= -1$, show that $DA \cdot DB = DC \cdot DO$, where O is the midpoint of the segment $AB$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, cross-ratio

> If ($ACBD$) $= -1$, show that $DA \cdot DB = DC \cdot DO$, where O is the midpoint of the segment $AB$.

My attempt to proof:

[image]

Suppose ($ACBD$) $= -1$ then $\frac{AC}{CB} = \frac{AD}{BD}$ then $AC \cdot BD = CB \cdot AD$. Also, since $O$ is a midpoint for $AB$  then $AO = OB$.

\begin{align*}
AC \cdot BD &= CB \cdot AD \\
\Longrightarrow (AD + DC) \cdot BD &= (CD + DB) \cdot(AO + OD) \\
\Longrightarrow AD \cdot BD + BD \cdot DC &= CD \cdot AO + DB \cdot OD + DB \cdot AO + CD \cdot OD \\
\Longrightarrow  AD \cdot BD - CD \cdot OD &= CD \cdot AO + DB \cdot DC + DB \cdot OD + DB \cdot AO \\
&= CD \cdot AO + DB \cdot DC + DB \cdot AD \\
&= CD \cdot AO + DB \cdot AC \\
&= (CA + AD) \cdot AO + (DA + AB) \cdot AC \\
&= CA \cdot AO + AD \cdot AO + DA \cdot AC + AB \cdot AC \\
&= AC \cdot (AB - AO) + DA \cdot (AC - AO) \\
&= AC(OB) + DA(OC)
\end{align*}
I'm stuck in this. Is my proof wrong? how to make the right hand side $0$?

Comment: Hint: If you let $AC=a, CB = b, BD = c$, then it's very trivial algebra. IE Show that if $ac = (a+b+c)b$, then $(a+b+c)(c) = (b+c) ( c + (a+b)/2)$.

Comment: is my proof wrong from the start?

Comment: The proof is not factually wrong, but it's hard to motivate what you're doing, and why. There are essentially 3 variables (which correspond to my $a, b, c$), but you're trying to play around with so many different line segments, it's hard to know what to head towards. Try my hint, and compare with what you're doing.

Comment: Can i see how the proof starts ?

Comment: Btw the topic is harmonic division by using it how to prove that

Comment: are you referring to my proof? If so, it's stated above. The only step that's missing is very direct algebraic manipulation. If you're stuck, show what you've tried.

Comment: I can't solve it using your hint

Comment: @CalvinLin btw thankyou sir

Comment: With regards to my approach, show what you've tried. If you're stuck, take the different of the 2 sides, and see what terms are left over.

Comment: what do you mean by taking the difference of the two sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrasing of problem statement

> Let $ A C = a, CB = b, BD = c$.
> We are given that $ac = (a+b+c)b$.
> WTS $(a+b+c)c = (b+c)(c+ (a+b)/2)$.

> Taking the difference of the 2 sides, and multiplying by 2
>  WTS $ -ab + ac - b^2 - bc = 0$.
>  Notice that this is exactly the condition $ac = (a+b+c)b$.    Hence we are done.

---

Note: If so desired, you can rephrase this in terms of $AC, CB, BD$, and use only those line segments, to make it clear what we should be focusing on.
Introducing line segments like $OA, OC$ etc makes it harder to manipulate, ad we should just replace them by $OA = (AC+CB)/2$, etc.

Comment: Thank you   very much

Comment: btw what do youmean by taking the difference of the 2 sides

Comment: @dominiceqrut Left hand side minus Right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch of another proof.**

Construct a point $X$ such that $CX\perp AB$. Let $H$ be the orthocenter of the triangle $ABX$ and $XC$, $AM$, $BN$ are the corresponding altitudes. Then,

- $M$, $N$ and $D$ are collinear (hint: use Ceva's and Menelaus' theorems);
- the quadrilaterals $ANMB$ and $ONMC$ are cyclic (hint: nine-point circle).

Thus, $DA\cdot DB=DM\cdot DN=DO\cdot DC$, as desired.

**Remark.** Of course, this is *much more* complicated than direct computation via lengths of segments. However, I thibk it's, firstly, very nice proof (you can play with this constrcuction more) and, secondly, it illustrates the principle of passing to the higher diimensions which is quite useful (see proofs of Desargues' theorem, for example).